# RDF vocabulary to specify a RDF resource IRI's structure

Tags: rdf, shacl, iri

I would like to encode how an IRI of a RDF resource should be constructed, also including the literals of the resource predicates. For example take this RDF resource

```
<> a :Dataset ;
  :published "2020-01-01"^^xsd:date ;
  :name "testDataset" .
```

How can I specify that I want the IRI to be `<some_prefix/20200101/testDataset>` where the values of `:published` and `:name` are used to create the IRI?
I am  interested in a method which does not involve SPARQL.
I am wondering if something like [JSON-Path](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/id/draft-goessner-dispatch-jsonpath-00.html) exists for RDF?
Or, is there an existing RDF vocabulary for declaring the structure of a string based on a RDF graph?

To give more context if needed: I am working on driving web forms with SHACL shapes. I am looking for a way of storing together with a shape the structure of the IRI that a newly generated RDF resource should have. I would like to be able to write something like the following:

```
:someShape a sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:targetClass :someClass ;
    rdfs:label "Some label" ;
    sh:property 
        :propA , 
        :propB ;
    :IRIStructure "http://some/base/IRI/[:propB]/foo/[:propA]"
```

Comment: Is your example notation sufficient for your case (i.e., using it would work for you, but you wonder if there is a standard/recommended notation), or is there a problem with it?

Comment: Yes I'm wondering if something already exists :)

Comment: About forms and IRI Templates have a look here https://t-code.pl/blog/2020/12/hydra-shacl-templates/

Comment: I don't know about anything like xPath or json-path but keep in mind XML and JSON are tree like and RDF is a graph. But maybe you find clownface interesting https://zazuko.github.io/clownface/#/